# Unexpected error while trying to find the longest string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I failed to write a program that prints the longest substring of a string in which the letters occur in alphabetical order for my very first Python test.

The comment read

> "Your program does meet what the question asks but also contradicts with rule number 4 and hence your answer will not be accepted"

So here was my attempt of the code :

```
def obtain_longest_substring(string):
    current_substring = longest_substring = string[0]
    for letter in string[1:]:
        if letter >= current_substring[-1]:
            current_substring += letter
            if len(current_substring) > len(longest_substring):
                longest_substring = current_substring
        else:
            current_substring = letter
    return longest_substring


def main():
    s = input("Enter a string: ")
    print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + obtain_longest_substring(s))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But the solution that was expected had some rules that I had to follow. Rule Number 4 said:

> For problems such as these, do not include input statements or define variables which are already mentioned. Our automated testing will provide values for you.

I am new to Python. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Read the assignment carefully. You say it asks for a *program*, but might it actually be a *procedure*? In that case it's (literally) the `input` line that is obsolete.

Comment: Read Rule Number 4 and look over your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule clearly states **not** to include `input` statements or define variables (which you also did).

You could try re-writing it as :

```
current_substring = longest_substring = s[0]
for letter in s[1:]:
    if letter >= current_substring[-1]:
        current_substring += letter
        if len(current_substring) > len(longest_substring):
            longest_substring = current_substring
    else:
        current_substring = letter

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " +   str(longest_substring))
```

Comment: Well if it works exactly the way you wanted, please click on the green tick on the left. That would take this answer as an accepted one :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The rule says "do not include input statements"; you included an input statement (in `main`).

Comment: Would a `main` then still be okay? Betraying my newbie status in Python. Are variables `global` enough to survive being pasted into just about any program?